# Mobile version of the app is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access

Tags: facebook, mobile, mobile-website

I don't see any requirements aside from the registration one here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/#register

I've set the Mobile Web URL to the secure canvas url, but am receiving the error Mobile version of the app [WishGenies](https://apps.facebook.com/wishgenies) is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access

The only other thing I see presumably has to do w/ the Auth Dialog page, but that just renders a blank screen for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The auth dialog page loading blank is unrelated and should be fixed shortly - where are you seeing that other message and what are you doing to trigger it?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so I finally figured out a little about this problem...

Somehow, when the request sends a referrer you get this error ( like a link through a http site ) linking from a https site, or getting the referrer out results in a correct redirect to the mobile site ...

Comment: Wow, that's weird behaviour.
Adding rel="noreferrer" to the <a> link works in my tests in the latest Safari (iOS), Android Browser and Chrome (Android). Although it doesn't appear to work in Android Firefox, so you might be best going with another solution.

Comment: well, since there isn't another solution ... and facebook doesn't know how to correctly develop stuffs then what?? , i actually use a proxy redirect now from https -> works

Answer (score 4):

Removing "app-domains" from your basic Facebook Settings will fix this problem.

Facebook bug: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/124226157757972

Answer (score 2):

The URL for the mobile version of your app must be distinct from the URL for your desktop app. It's a weird constraint, but that's probably what's keeping your app from working.

Comment: As of March 2013, I don't find this. My mobile and canvas URL are the same and I am not having problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had to set Mobile URL to blank under Basic App Settings.  And also I had to add  rel="noreferrer" on my website.  I believe this makes the Mobile URL referrer match the actual referrer because they are both an empty string.

It would probably also work if you had a mobile site URL other than your desktop site and the referrer matched when you direct users to Facebook.