# Application is misconfigured

Tags: mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a mobile web application, some times it is showing that "the mobile version of the app is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access". Why this is happening? I noticed that it is happening when user is logout form Fb and try to come back to the app it showing login form after login it showing the error.

Please help

Comment: I solved the problem, I use direct url's where we host the codes in the app

Comment: Can you explain this a little further?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441757/mobile-version-of-the-app-is-unavailable-because-it-is-misconfigured-for-mobile/14503284#14503284

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and what was seemed to be the issue was that if you just got redirected from Facebook to your app, and then instantly redirected back to apps.facebook.com/my-app/sub-uri then Facebook raises an error.

This is what I was doing and what I ended up doing:

I tried to authorize my app, authorization through redirect to Facebook and after authorizing the app redirected to my apps.facebook.com/my-namespace/next-step.

Visiting with a mobile device and redirecting back to Facebook, after Facebook just had redirected your user to the app, caused an error.

I then added a piece of mobile sniffing code and if the user was mobile it redirected internally to /next-step instead of going to apps.facebook.com.

Initial request flow for mobile:

```
my.domain.tld/authorize 
-> graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize 
<- my.domain.tld/authorized 
-> apps.facebok.com/my-app/next-step 

error
```

Which I then changed to this if the user was mobile:

```
my.domain.tld/authorize 
-> graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize 
<- my.domain.tld/authorized 
-> my.domain.tld/next-step 

All working fine
```

Comment: Answered this so long after the fact because it's the first SO hit on Google for this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your's Native iOS or Android Apps Bundle ID in Facebook developer page